# python list scope in class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am coming up against some unexpected behavior with this code:

```
from pprint import pprint

class a (object):
    x = ['1']

class b (a):
    x = a.x
    x.append('2')

class c (a):
    x = a.x
    x.append('3')

class d (a):
    x = a.x
    x = 'nothing'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pprint(a.x)
    pprint(b.x)
    pprint(c.x)
    pprint(d.x)
```

I receive the output:

```
['1', '2', '3']
['1', '2', '3']
['1', '2', '3']
'nothing'
```

But I would expect to receive:

```
['1']
['1', '2']
['1', '3']
'nothing'
```

What I don't understand is:

1. Why does appending to a list in class b also append to the list in class a?
2. Why does appending to that list in class c append to both b and a?
3. Why doesn't re-assigning that variable to a string in class d not have an effect on the other 3 classes?

Comment: This has **nothing** to do with scope. You've simply assigned *the same list*, the one that was originally in `a`, to **all the `x`** attributes of your other classes, `x = a.x`...

Comment: The assignment *will be to that class variable*, the other class variables are not affected by assignment.

Comment: You may now think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) or comment one to get details ;) to reward those who spent time for you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define it this way. The variable x is initialised with the parent class and each child that inherits the class takes a reference to the variable (not a copy). It becomes a global variable under the class name.

To achieve the output you expected:

```
from pprint import pprint

class a (object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = ['1']

class b (a):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.x.append('2')

class c (a):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.x.append('3')

class d (a):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.x = 'nothing'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pprint(a().x)
    pprint(b().x)
    pprint(c().x)
    pprint(d().x)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your line

```
class b (a):
    x = a.x
```

creates another "name" for `a.x`, namely `x` (in that scope), but they are the same object. If you append to `x`, you are also appending to `a.x` - it is appending to the same object.

The only place you do something different is in

```
x = 'nothing'
```

where you are now binding `x` to a different object, a string.

---

If you would change your code to

```
class b (a):
    x = a.x.copy()
```

you would get different behaviour: that says that `x` is now a "name" for a copy of the list that is `a.x`.

Answer (score 2):

**1. 2.** When doing `x = a.x` you're just assigning `x` to point the to the only existing list, the one from `a` so when operating on `x` this reflects on `a.x` because this is the same list, not a copy. This is both correct for `class b` and `class c`. To do a copy

```
x = list(a.x)
```

**3.** When doing `x='nothing'` you're assigning a string into `x` which doesn't point anymore to the list, just that

Answer (score 0):

This is probably one of the hardest things for new Python developers to understand and it becomes a real epiphany when they finally do. What you have there is no different to:

```
>>> x = [1]; print(x)
[1]

>>> y = x; print(x); print(y)
[1]
[1]

>>> y.append(2); print(x); print(y)
[1, 2]
[1, 2]

>>> z = x; z = 'nothing'; print(x); print(y); print(z)
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
nothing
```

The reason is does this is because, in Python, everything is an object and variables are simply *bindings* to objects.

So `x = [1]` creates the *object* `[1]` and binds the `x` variable to it.

When you then do `y = x`, that *doesn't* create a new object, it simply binds `y` to the already-existing object. That means `x` and `y` are now both bound to the *same* object so, when you do an operation that modifies the object, like `x.append()`, both `x` and `y` will be affected.

That *doesn't* occur with `z = x; z = 'nothing'` since the second step there is creating a *new* object and binding `z` to it, so that `x/y` and `z` are now bound to different things.

It also doesn't occur with either of:

```
z = x[:]
z = [item for item in x]
```

since both of those also create a new object (a copy of the original<sup>(1)</sup>), separating `x` and `z`.

The effect can be seen by examining the IDs of each variable (probably the only reason you should ever use `id`), with common prefix removed for readability:

```
>>> print(id(x)); print(id(y)); print(id(z))
49864
49864
53808
```

You can see that `x` and `y` are the *same* object, and `z` is different.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Keep in mind you may need to do a *deep* copy if your data structures are sufficiently complex, such as (with comments added):

```
>>> x = [[1,2],[3,4]]; y = x; print(id(x)); print(id(y))
773190920  # same object
773190920

>>> y = x[:]; print(id(x)); print(id(y))
773190920  # different objects
832649864

>>> print(id(x[0])); print(id(y[0]))
773088840  # but the sub-objects are still identical.
773088840
```